# jquery iframe content is not drag using jquery ui draggable

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to apply Jquery UI draggable function to iframe contents, so we can drag it in iframe . If yes, then how?

Comment: Do you mean drag into and out of an iframe? Otherwise, yes, considering the iframe is its own document.

Comment: No not into and out , just drag it inside the iframe that`s it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer is no: http://jsfiddle.net/8NN9Y/14/

Consider using another tag, like a div

http://jsfiddle.net/8NN9Y/15/

Comment: thanks for answer but , but if u can show me 1 example then it will much heplful for me or give me any link where i will get more info about this

Comment: Question: why do you need to use an iframe? this would be way easier if it where just a <div> or any other tag

Comment: ya u r right <div> is much easier way than iframe but i just want to know how we can drag the iframe content inside the iframe using jquery ui draggable, if u know than pls tell me the way with example

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late in the day, but it might help others who stumble over this post. If I understand you properly you want to drag the contents of an iframe *within* an iframe? This should be possible - but you need to include the relevant javascript libraries to the script *in* the iframe - not the parent. So in this example...

```
<iframe src="contentIwantToDrag.html"></frame>
```

Your page `contentIwantToDrag.html` should include the jQuery and UI libraries.

If you are wanting to drag items from inside the iframe into the parent element then this is not possible as far as I understand.